# Tag burnination request: [unexpected-result]

Tags: discussion, tags

[unexpected-result](/questions/tagged/unexpected-result) is a dictionary-definition meta tag:

1. There is no reasonable way that the tag could stand alone as the only tag on the question.
2. None of the questions have anything in common at all, other than the vague concept of "I didn't expect that."  As a result, the tag means different things to different people.

It currently has about 40 questions, which is over my personal treshold for just doing it unilaterally.

Unless anyone has any strong feelings about it, I'll be manually removing the tag from all questions some time tomorrow.

Comment: You have to imagine that if they received the expected result, they just...wouldn't have asked a question. The tags people come up with...

Comment: No! I think it's a perfectly valid tag, and should be added to about 95% of the questions on the site! :P

Comment: I'd say it's textbook-useless, but not technically a meta tag.  It doesn't describe the question in the same way a tag like `subjective` would.

Comment: First question I encounter also has the tag [tag:floating-accuracy], with 82 followers.  Sheesh.

Comment: If I got the expected result but don't like it can I ask SO how to alter reality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed all the questions from the [unexpected-result](/questions/tagged/unexpected-result) tag.